# Fail with checking if an app is installed iOS

Tags: ios, swift, url, info.plist

I have already read about `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL`. But in my case it somehow doesn't work. I have a scheme:

[image]

If I have `VK app` installed, the url `vk://` works, and Safari successfully asks me if I want to open this app. On this step, `canOpenURL` returns `true`.

If the app is not installed, Safari says, that the url is invalid. But `canOpenURL` still returns `true`.

What's going on? Does `canOpenURL` check only syntax of the URL? Then how must I check if the app is installed?

Comment: According to Apple's Docs on `canOpenURL:` `the system tests the URL’s scheme to determine if there is an installed app that is registered to handle the scheme.`
Is it possible there is another app registered with that scheme?

Comment: Have you added the URL to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key? This doesn't seem to be what you have shown in screen shot.

Comment: @Peter , indeed!  There was something animalistic! In `URL Types`, in `URL Schemes` field, there was `vk` stroke, separated by a comma, though I exactly remember, that I didn't write it :D . I deleted `vk`, checked without it, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

For open app from deep linking you should also write some lines of code for schema and URL::

```
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if(url.absoluteString == "appname://app/https://appurl"){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if defaults.objectForKey("access_token") != nil {
         // check condition what you want for open specific page
        }
        else{
            let loginVC: LoginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
        }
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```